# Создание Custom Control в Silverlight (ComboBox+TreeView+Поиск)

Tags: customview, c#, silverlight, xaml, wpf

Всем доброго времени суток.

У меня имеется затруднение с созданием кастом контрола в Silverlight. Мне необходимо создать следующий элемент: ComboBox с функцией поиска элементов, а элемент при этом должен быть TreeView. То есть при введении критериев в строке поиска, должны сортироваться элементы TreeView и оставаться только те, которые соответствуют критериям поиска.

Простой [TreeViewComboBox](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/29647980/ComboBoxTreeView.png) мне удалось создать (нашел шаблон и подогнал под требования, а теперь требования изменились). Простой ComboBox с функцией поиска я [нашел](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55993/AutoComplete-ComboBox-for-Silverlight) и он собирается из AutoCompleteBox и чёрной магии..

Я вот просто думаю, что изобретаю велосипед и может быть у кого-то завалялся такой компонент в закромах и ему не жалко поделиться?

Заранее благодарен!